# Confirmation message from the ASP.NET code behind file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a login screen Login.aspx after login I want to show a confirmation message saying

"You are being redirected to the Demo page. Do you want to continue?",

if the user clicked yes, I need to redirect them to a demo page. Other wise redirect to another home page. How can I do this?

I want something like the following...

```
protected void Login_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
       {
          //some validation and calculations..

          ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "confirm('You are redirecting to Demo page ". Do you want to continue" ?');", true);


          //My doubt is this
          If(ok button clicked)
          {
             //redirect to demo page
          }
          else
          {
             //redirect to home page
          }

       }
```

Comment: Please have the user messages reviewed by a native speaker. English doesn't have spaces before the dot at the end of a sentence and "You are redirecting to Demo page." is ungrammatical (do you mean "You are being redirected to the Demo page"? or "You are redirecting us to a demo page"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wont get the result of confirm on server side. You can call a javascript function RegisterStartupScript and put this confirm dialog in that function.

Although you can somehow send value of confirm on server side using postback of some ajax call but I do not see any reason for that.

*Code behind*

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "RedirectDecision();", true);
```

*Html*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function RedirectDecision()
    {     
         if(confirm('You are redirecting to Demo page ". Do you want to continue" ?'))
             window.location = "http://www.yoururlFirst.com";
         else
             window.location = "http://www.yoururlSecond.com";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: :Is there any method to get result of confirm on server side??

Comment: You can return it through post back or ajax call.

Comment: i need to add some piece of formauthentication codes inside the confirmation click button. So i want to the get result of confirm click in code behind can you help me??

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you want with confirmation result?

Comment: Actually the rquirement is like ,if the user clicked yes in the confirmation message the login should continue and redirect to demo page. and if clicked no the current user should logout and continue to home (default page). Iam using form authentication...FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage(); should use in confirmation no block...

Comment: You can redirect to home page and pass some value using query string indicating that you should logout the user

Comment: How can i implement that??

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5876/Passing-variables-between-pages-using-QueryString

Comment: i was asking whether i need to use in window.location = "http://www.yoururlFirst.com?querystring"; like that in your javascript function...

Comment: Yes, something like this "yoururlFirst.com?lt=y"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79617/discussion-between-athul-and-adil).

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. You can call a client side function by setting `OnClientClick`. If user will press confirm than `code behind` function will be called. Have a look at below example

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2"  OnClick="Login_Click" OnClientClick="return UserConfirmation()"   runat="server" Text="Login" />

function UserConfirmation() {
  if(confirm('You are redirecting to Demo page ". Do you want to continue" ?'))
     return true;
  else
     return false;

    }
```

Here if user will press `ok` than `code behind` function will be called other wise it won't